# InterstitialAd advert cancelled when requested - UWP - Windows 10

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've just created 2 new Ad Units in my Microsoft Dev Dashboard to handle `InterstitialAd`on both PC/Tablets and Mobile.

I initialize my `InterstitialAd` first:

```
// Instantiate the interstitial video ad
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd();

// Attach event handlers
interstitialAd.ErrorOccurred += OnAdError;
interstitialAd.AdReady += OnAdReady;
interstitialAd.Cancelled += OnAdCancelled;
interstitialAd.Completed += OnAdCompleted;
```

Then I've got the following code to request the relevant `InterstitialAd` advert based on the platform being used:

```
#if DEBUG
    interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", 
    "11389925");
    Debug.WriteLine("Page_Loaded - RequestAd: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
#else
    #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, MAppId, MAdUnitId);
    #else
        interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, WAppId, WAdUnitId);
    #endif
#endif
```

It works as expected when in `Debug` mode, but when in `Release` mode, the second the relevant `interstitialAd.RequestAd` is called, the `OnAdCancelled` method is called.

I've double checked the values associated with `MappId`, `MAdUnitId`, `WAppId` and `WAdUnitId` and they all are definitely correct and associated with the correct platform being used.

Any ideas??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug where if you use slightly more complex conditional statements, it throws this error. I had to change my code to the following to get rid of this error:

```
var myAppId = "";
var myAdUnitId = "";

//Test Ids
//myAppId = "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab";
//myAdUnitId = "11389925";

//Windows Store AppId;
myAppId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
myAdUnitId = "xxxxxxxx";

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    myAppId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    myAdUnitId = "xxxxxx";
#endif

interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, myAppId, myAdUnitId);
```

And after having wasted so much time on this, I found out that there is no Interstitial Advert in my region.

Hope this helps others!